# How to simplify this huge expression to get a known smaller expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following massive expression

```
A = ((8 - 2 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + q (-6 + 3 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + q (-17 + 12 q - 4 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q])))/Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + (Sqrt[2] (24 + 2 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + q (-5 (10 + 3 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q]) + q (-95 + 7 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + q (323 - 196 q + 12 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q])))))/Sqrt[-q (-8 + 7 q) (2 + 2 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + q (-10 + 21 q - 7 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q]))])/(8 (-1 + q) (-1 + 2 q))
```

I have reason to believe that this is simply equal to

```
B =(4 - 16 q^2)/(3 q - 4 Sqrt[8 - 7 q] q^(3/2) + Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q])
```

for $0 < q < 1/2$. Numerically, they agree to 100 digits and their plots look identical. My question is: how can I use `FullSimplify` (or the like) on the first expression to get something of the same complexity as the second expression? In other words, I'm more interested in simplifying the first expression than I am actually checking that it's equal to the second. I've tried modifying the complexity function to `Composition[StringLength, ToString]` but it doesn't really get there.

Comment: You mean how would we simplify if we didn't already know the simpler expression?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, exactly. I'm hoping to apply the simplification method to other expressions I have, where I don't have a good guess for the simpler form.

Comment: Sometimes it's more productive to look at how the expression was derived, go back to the starting point, and try to write *the starting point* in a simpler form. E.g., identify common subexpressions such as `Sqrt[(8-7q)q]`, and use a more compact notation (single letter) for them during the derivation. I find that manual derivations often give more insight than automated ones precisely because we tend to keep track of "meaningful subexpressions".

Comment: For what it's worth, `FullSimplify[A == B, 0 < q < 1/2]` returns `True` in seconds.

Comment: `ComplexityFunction -> cf`, with `cf[e_] := LeafCount[e] + 100 Count[e, Power[__, z_] /; z != -1, Infinity]` does not help either.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I would like to know how you arrived at `B` as a simplification of `A`, which it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use substitution of variables and let `a = Sqrt[(8-7q)q]`

Then there is an intermediate step of:

```
((8 - 2 a + q (-6 + 3 a + q (-17 + 12 q - 4 a)))/a + 
  (Sqrt[2] 
     (24 + 2 a + q (-5 (10 + 3 a) + q (-95 + 7 a + q (323 - 196 q + 12 a))))) / 
     Sqrt[-q (-8 + 7 q) (2 + 2 a + q (-10 + 21 q - 7 a))])/(8 (-1 + q) (-1 + 2 q))
```

You can then do more algebra.

Perhaps on your domain `Sqrt[-q (-8 + 7 q)]`  will be related directly to `a`.

The remaining algebra can be done by those interested.

Comment: Did you mean to add something more to this post?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify.  I think there are a number of further simplifications that can be made, but I just don't have time to do that right now.

Comment: This turned out to be essentially the solution; identify terms that show up often and replace them with something simpler.

Answer (score 2):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER**

```
A = ((8 - 2 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + 
        q (-6 + 3 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + q (-17 + 12 q - 4 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q])))/
      Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + (Sqrt[
         2] (24 + 2 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + 
          q (-5 (10 + 3 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q]) + 
             q (-95 + 7 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + 
                q (323 - 196 q + 12 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q])))))/
      Sqrt[-q (-8 + 7 q) (2 + 2 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q] + 
          q (-10 + 21 q - 7 Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q]))])/(8 (-1 + q) (-1 + 2 q));

B = (4 - 16 q^2)/(3 q - 4 Sqrt[8 - 7 q] q^(3/2) + Sqrt[(8 - 7 q) q]);
```

Both `A` and `B` have almost the same domain, differing only at `q == 8/7`

```
FunctionDomain[#, q] & /@ {A, B}

(* {0 < q < 1/2 || 1/2 < q < 1 || 1 < q < 8/7, 
    0 < q < 1/2 || 1/2 < q < 1 || 1 < q <= 8/7} *)

Plot[{A, B}, {q, 0, 8/7},
 Exclusions -> {0, 1/2, 1, 8/7},
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed},
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"A", "B"}, {.25, .2}]]
```

[image]

As seen in the plot above, `A` and `B` are equal in the restricted domain `0 < q < 1/2`

```
A == B // FullSimplify[#, 0 < q < 1/2] &

(* True *)
```

Comment: I do not think that `RootReduce` does anything in this case.  `A === A2` yields `True`.  Moreover, the `Out` forms of both look the same, even though the `In` forms doe not..

Comment: @bbgodfrey - Thanks. My mistake -- up too late last night.